# I Need proper book or paper on Lie algebras and PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-algebras, book-recommendation

I have keen desire to study applications of Lie algebras in PDE. I was googling for some introduction or review papers / books regarding applications of non-associative algebras (Lie algebras) in PDE, but I was confused by a lot of papers. 
May you please help me the right source for mentioned topic. Need to say, I have very good knowledge on Lie algebras.

Comment: There is a book [Representations of Lie Algebras and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9789811063909).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest Peter Olver's *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations*.